# Return error message from observer Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I made a custom module for observer on customer save before event for admin-side

My config file in local/Pavans/Profile/etc

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <pavans_profile>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Pavans_Profile_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
                    </pavans_profile>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_before>

        </events>

    </adminhtml>
```

It calls my observer before customer data saved

```
class Pavans_Profile_Model_Observer {
    public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    { 
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        $response = array('error' => false, 'message' => $helper->__('Error'));
        return $controller->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));    

    }
}
```

I want to pass error message on customer form and stop controller to save customer data, but above code shows me error message

```
 Call to a member function setFlag() on a non-object
```

So i'm unable to get object of controller.

I have also tried this

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
$action = $request->getActionName();
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag($action, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
$response = Mage::app()->getResponse();

$json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('error' => -1, 'message' => $this->__('test errror'))); 
$response->setBody($json);
```

This shows me Error message on form

> An error occurred while saving the customer

Above message is not my custom error message

Comment: why you used this ->setFlag()

Comment: 'FLAG_NO_DISPATCH' Stop executing Controller Action So No customer data saved and we can show our error message

Comment: when you got error?? frontend ya backend

Comment: setflag not working on both side, and that your code below in your answer shows 'Cannot save the customer' error not my custom error on front-side And 'An error occurred while saving the customer.' in back-end. currently i only want for back-end. I'm using magento 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag($action, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true)
```

used

```
  $response->setHttpResponseCode(500);
```

try this for

```
public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    { 
    try {
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
         Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('error' => -1, 'message' => $this->__('test errror'))));
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
       Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody($e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer move error'.$e));
        Mage::logException($e);
    }

}
```

See at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290639/in-an-observer-method-how-do-you-tell-magento-to-not-process-code-after-the-dis

**edit:**
Can try 
200 instead of 500

Or Try this

```
public function customerSaveAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
    { 

            $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

            $controller=Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();

            if( Mage::app()->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() || Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
                // Is ajax
                $action = $request->getActionName();
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag(
                        $action, Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);

                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(200);
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('error' => -1, 'message' => $this->__('test error'))));

            } else {
               // Is form submit
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
                    ->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('test error.'));
               Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
                    ->setCustomerFormData(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost());
               Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
            }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this one. This shows me Error message on form 'An error occurred while saving the customer' Not my custom error message.I don't know why its not working.

Comment: My code for admin-side goes to Is form submit section so i changed 'customer/session' to 'core/session'. But its showing error but also saving all data , so customer saved successfully message. I added  Mage::app()->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array('error' => -1, 'message' => $this->__('test error')))); . Now its showing me both custom error and 'An error occurred while saving the customer.' as before. this also stopped customer data saving. So i'm using it. Thanks :)

Comment: can you send me exception.log and system.log.thus i check where the issue

Comment: Only one system log :- '2014-09-01T14:01:04+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in C:\wamp\www\magentoanifit\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3941'

Comment: using this event you want  to prevent data save?

Comment: Yes, And above as my comment before, Its doing so currently i'm using it.

Answer (score 9):

Just throw an Exception:

```
Mage::throwException('My Error message')
```

Than the save is avoided and the error message is shown

Comment: Thanks alot. But this error is not showing on form but on listing on admin-side, though its showing error on form on front-side.

Comment: Is this an AJAX call, so no magento core code?

Comment: Its on adnin-side so its an ajax call, With above code page redirect to listing of all customers and shows our error message.

Comment: ah, got it. In which context are you? You can only check the code for anything which helps you with your task. Creating a new customer? Creating a new customer to create an order?

Comment: On admin-side i have a custom attribute 'webname', for which i need to do some validation. And if validation fails want to throw error.

Comment: You should checkout `\Mage_Eav_Model_Form::validateData` , especially where this $dataModel comes from and who to utilize it for what you want to do.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Could you pls help me,  In my case, observer return throw exception, logic not load https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284557/57334